# Can' log into Ubuntu using GUI

Tags: unity, upgrade, package-management, login

Evening.

I recently upgrade Ubuntu to 17.04 and ran into a problem. I can log into any user that existed in my machine, but only when dropping to the terminal. I cannot do that by regular means in the Ubuntu splash screen. I started looking into it and looks like the package gnome-session is not getting installed because there is a missing dependency for it. The exact problem is that somewhere during the upgrade, the following package had a problem: 3.24.0-0Ubuntu1.

I tried installing, purging and autocleaning several times but I keep getting the following problem:

```
gnome-session: Depends: gnome-session-bin (>=3.24.0-0Ubuntu) but 3.18.1.2-1Ubuntu1.16.04.2 is to installed.
```

Has anybody run into this issue?

NOTE: I tried installing another of the dependencies and I got the following:

gnome-session-bin: Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or libgles2.

I tried another command here to see if I could reinstall my desktop.

apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop and got the following error:

ubuntu-desktop: Depends: ubuntu-session but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: unity8-desktop-session but it is not going to be installed
E: unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Thanks,
Raf

Comment: Did you also try `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`? `-f` is for "try to automatically fix broken dependencies"

Comment: Indeed I did. I jumped into google and some people recommend doing this with aptitude. I am installing it right now to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

Used aptitude instead of apt. Aptitude had no problem install ubuntu-desktop from scratch. After that, the account login problems went away.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Raf